# Yii2 results from orm in mapped array

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a way using yii2 orm or command builder to retrieve results from db as mapped array like array where key is ID and Value is some column from array ?

Like

```
OacAreacode::find()->asArray("areacode", "id")->all();
```

ive experimented with

```
ArrayHelper::map(OacAreacode::find()->all(), "areacode", "id");
```

But its very slow.

Comment: If you're going to `map()` the result. You might as well `asArray()` the query first. This will keep yii2 from generating all the models and save on execution time and memory. Whether or not that will be fast enough I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `createCommand` and `queryAll` with `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` params like that

```
$res = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT id, areacode FROM areacode')->queryAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first example is almost right.  You would want to do something like this

```
OacAreacode::find()->select(['areacode', 'id'])->asArray()->all();
```